# ajax form submit -> receive respone from php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've been reading multiple threads about similar cases but even now I'm still unable to do it correctly.

**What I want to do**
Basically, i.e. I have form which allows user to change his login (simply query to database). 
**PHP script looks like that:**

```
if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
        $doEdit = $user->editData("login", $_POST['login']);
        if($doEdit) {
            $result = displayInfobox('success', 'Good!');
        } else {
            $result = displayInfobox('warning', 'Bad!');
        }   
    } else {
        $error = 'Bad!';
        echo $error;
    }
```

displayInfobox is just a div with class i.e. success and content - Good!.

Right now I would like to send this form by AJAX and display $result without reloading page.

**HTML:**

```
<form id="changeLogin" method="post" class="form-inline" action="usercp.php?action=editLogin">
        <label for="login">Login:</label><br />
        <div class="form-group ">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="login" id="login" required>
            <input type="submit" value="Zmień"  class="btn btn-primary">
        </div>
    </form>
```

**And finnally - my jquery/ajax:**

```
$("#changeLogin").submit(function(e) {

  var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
  var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
  $.ajax({
    url: formURL,
    type: "POST",
    data: postData,
    success: function(result) {
      alert(result);
    },
    error: function(response) {}
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});

$("#changeLogin").submit();
```

If I leave "success" blank, it works -> form is submitted by ajax, login changed, but I do not see the result message. Otherwise whole page get reloaded.
Also, when I hit F5 form is being submited once again (even in Ajax).

Comment: is the second `$("#changeLogin").submit();` in your code??

Comment: also no need to define `action`in html-form and then grab it from there. Leave it empty and set the url in js.

Answer (score 1):

I cant add comments because i do not have enough reputation but...

You should delete the last line with `$("#changeLogin").submit();`

And then in your php script file you should echo the result so you can get this result in ajax request. After that in your success method you have to read the result and (for example) append it somewhere to show the success or error box

Comment: Thanks! Did that + filtered the result and it seems to work. Just can't figure out how to use filter() properly -> The result is in div with some class, when I filter it I got the content of the div, instead of the whole div with its classes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a normal button instead of submit button,just onclick can be an ajax request, the form should not be submitted,good luck.